# image link with url not getting table values

Tags: cakephp

```
<?php 
        echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('files/user/photo/'.$row['User']['photo_dir'].'/'.$row['User']['photo'], array('width' => '200', 'height' => '200')) . ' ' . __('user image'),
                       array('controller'=>'Profiles'),
                       array('escape' => false),$row['User']['id']);?>
```

here i tried code like

```
<a href="profiles/index/<?php echo $row['User']['id']; ?>"><img src="files/user/photo/<?php echo ($row['User']['photo_dir']).'/'.($row['User']['photo']);?>" width="200" height="200"/> </a>
```

but in cake php page the image url and image name are not getting..html works but cakephp core code not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->link(
         $this->Html->image('../files/user/photo/'.$row['User']['photo_dir'].'/'.$row['User']['photo'], 
             array(
                'width' => '48', 
                'height' => '48'
             )),
         array(
             'controller'=>'Profiles',
             'action'=>'index',
             $row['User']['id']
         ),
         array('escape' => false)
     );
?>
```